# Proving Uniform Convergence of Sinc Function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, uniform-convergence

> Let $f$ be the sinc function, defined by \begin{equation}
>  {\rm{f}}(t)=
>    \begin{cases}
>    \frac{ \sin(2\pi t)}{2\pi t}  \qquad &t \not= 0\\ \\
>    1\qquad & t =0
>     \end{cases}
>     \end{equation}

> For each integer $n \geq 0$, define  \begin{equation}{\rm{f_n}}(t)=
>    \begin{cases}
>    f(t)  \qquad &t \in [n,n+1)\\ \\
>    0\qquad & otherwise
>     \end{cases}
>     \end{equation}
> Prove that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$.

So for uniform convergence I need to prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg(sup|f(t) - f_n(t)| \bigg ) = 0 $$ So far I found that $$\lim_{t \to \pm \infty}f(t) = 0 $$ and $$\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(t) = 0 $$ But in general $sup|f(t) - f_n(t)| > 0$ since $f(t) = 1$ for $t = 0$, so Im struggling to see how $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f(t)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $n\in\Bbb Z_+$ and each $x\in[0,\infty)$,$$f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^nf_k(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x<n+1\\\dfrac{\sin(2\pi x)}{2\pi x}&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$and therefore$$\left|f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^nf_k(x)\right|\leqslant\frac1{2\pi x}\leqslant\frac1{2\pi(n+1)}$$if $x\geqslant n+1$ (and $\left|f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^nf_n(x)\right|=0$ otherwise), So$$\sup_{x\in[0,\infty)}\left|f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^nf_k(x)\right|\leqslant\frac1{2\pi(n+1)}.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: For the first part did you mean to write $0$ if $ x \in [n,n+1)$ ? Also what about for $t = 0$?

Comment: I wrote *exactly* what I meant other than the fact that I used the symbol $t$ instead of $x$ (that has been edited).

Comment: I see how to finish the proof, but I honestly don't understand at all how you found $$f(x) - \sum_{k= 0}^\infty f_n(x)$$ its just extremely confusing to calculate with how the functions are defined.

Comment: I wrote about $\displaystyle f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^nf_k(x)$, not about $\displaystyle f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_n(x)$.

Comment: How does $f_k(x)$ relate to $f_n(t)$? I don't see how to conclude the proof without knowing their mathematical relation.

Comment: What do you mean? You understand what $f_n(x)$ is but not what $f_k(x)$ is? Is that it? I can edit my answer using only $f_n$ instead of $f_k$, but I don't see the point of doing that. What's the relevance of the letter that I chose to use? If I had used $m$ instead of $k$ it would be fine, as far as you are concerned?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood sorry. So $f_n(t)$ and $f_k(x)$ are the same? Then I understand.

Comment: To be clear: they are the same if $n=k$.